# ¿como guardar el id de un combobox?

Tags: php, html5, ajax, mysqli

Tengo una tabla costos que tiene la foranea de tabla actividad

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ingreso los costos mediante un modal, done se encuentra un combobox del nombre de la actividad(foranea de la tabla actividad) y en el value tengo el id_actividad. `echo '<option value="'.$valores['id_actividad'].'">'.$valores['n_actividad'].'</option>'`
Lo que no logro es que, al momento de seleccionar el nombre, me guarde solo el id de ese dato.

modal para ingreso de costos

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="modalNuevo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
       <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Agrega nueva persona</h4>
        </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
         

         
    <label>Nombre actividad:</label> 
    <select class="form-control" id="id_actividad_costo" required>
        <?php
                            
        $sql = ("SELECT * FROM `actividad` ORDER BY `n_actividad` ASC");
         $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
         while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
            
         echo '<option value="'.$valores['id_actividad'].'">'.$valores['n_actividad'].'</option>';
             
         }
    
        ?> 
        
    </select>
         

    <label>Numero de estudiantes:</label> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numero_estudiantes" onkeyup="sumar();">
    
    <label>Traslado:</label> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="traslado" onkeyup="sumar();">
    
    <label>Colacion:</label> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="colacion" onkeyup="sumar();">
   
    <label>Materiales:</label> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="materiales" onkeyup="sumar();">
    
    <label>Servicio de cafe:</label> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="servicio_cafe" onkeyup="sumar();">
    
    <label>Pago de ayudante:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pago_ayudante" onkeyup="sumar();">
    
    <label>Otros:</label> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="otros" onkeyup="sumar();">
    
     <label>Total:</label> 
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total" disabled value="0">
            
             
             
         </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="guardarnuevo">
        Agregar
        </button>
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#tabla').load('componentes/tabla.php');
    $('#buscador').load('componentes/buscador.php');
 });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#guardarnuevo').click(function(){
          id_actividad_costo=$('#id_actividad_costo').val();
          numero_estudiantes=$('#numero_estudiantes').val();
          traslado=$('#traslado').val();
          colacion=$('#colacion').val();
          materiales=$('#materiales').val();
          servicio_cafe=$('#servicio_cafe').val();
          pago_ayudante=$('#pago_ayudante').val();
          otros=$('#otros').val();
          total=$('#total').val();
            agregardatos( id_actividad_costo, numero_estudiantes, traslado, colacion, materiales, servicio_cafe, pago_ayudante, otros, total);
        });



        $('#actualizadatos').click(function(){
          actualizaDatos();
        });

    });
</script>
```

agregardatos.php

```js
<?php 

 require_once "conexion.php";
 $conexion=conexion();
    $id_costo=$_POST['id_costo'];
    $id_actividad_costo=$_POST['id_actividad_costo'];
 $numero_estudiantes=$_POST['numero_estudiantes'];
 $traslado=$_POST['traslado'];
    $colacion=$_POST['colacion'];
    $materiales=$_POST['materiales'];
    $servicio_cafe=$_POST['servicio_cafe'];
    $pago_ayudante=$_POST['pago_ayudante'];
    $otros=$_POST['otros'];
    $total=$_POST['total'];

 $sql="INSERT into costos (id_actividad_costo, numero_estudiantes, traslado, colacion, materiales, servicio_cafe, pago_ayudante, otros, total)
values ('$id_actividad_costo','$numero_estudiantes', '$traslado','$colacion','$materiales','$servicio_cafe','$pago_ayudante','$otros','$total')";
 echo $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

 ?>
```

ajax agregar los datos
funciones.js

```js
function agregardatos(id_actividad_costo, numero_estudiantes, traslado, colacion, materiales, servicio_cafe, pago_ayudante,otros,total){

 cadena="id_actividad_costo=" + id_actividad_costo +
            "&numero_estudiantes=" + numero_estudiantes + 
   "&traslado=" + traslado +
            "&colacion=" + colacion +
            "&materiales=" + materiales +
            "&servicio_cafe=" + servicio_cafe +
            "&pago_ayudante=" + pago_ayudante +
            "&otros=" + otros +
            "&total=" + total ;

    $.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"php/agregarDatos.php",
  data:cadena,
        beforeSend: function() {
        console.log(cadena);
        },
  success:function(r){
   if(r==1){
    $('#tabla').load('componentes/tabla.php');
     $('#buscador').load('componentes/buscador.php');
    alertify.success("agregado con exito :)");
   }else{
    alertify.error("Fallo el servidor :(");
   }
  }
 });


}
```

Comment: Puedes confirmar que la funcion agregardatos tiene el valor correcto en el parametro id_actividad_costo?

Comment: esa es mi duda como le paso el valor correcto a id_actividad_costo que debería ser el id_activdad del nombre que selecciona en combobox, ejemplo selecciono topografía(nombre de la actividad) que tiene id_actividad = 20, como le puedo pasar el 20 a id_actividad_costo, porque esta recibiendo topografía y por eso me arroja error

Comment: Como estas pasando valores a la funcion?  Pon el codigo donde la llamas.

Comment: edito de inmediato, se me olvido colocar el script

Comment: Lee sobre inyección SQL y cómo evitarla en PHP. Este código es vulnerable a ese tipo de ataques y no debería usarse en entornos públicos.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia esta linea:

```
id_actividad_costo=$('#id_actividad_costo').val();
```

Por esto:

```
id_actividad_costo=$('#id_actividad_costo').find('option:selected').val();
```

Comment: lo hice, pero sigue arrojando el error de no ingresar. Sin embargo, me di cuenta que aunque no guarde el Id sigue corriendo.

Comment: Pero ahora si te da el valor correcto o no?